# Publish ASP.NET Core with MSBuild 15

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild

In my company, we have some projects using .NET Framework (4.5.1) and one project using .NET Core.

Currently, all the .NET Framework projects are built with MSBuild.exe (version 12) and i would like to update the build to use MSBuild 15 so i would be able to build both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects in the same build.

Currently, the build compiles successfully when i'm building only my .NET Core project. But i wish to publish it, and the build result is not my desired outcome as it doesn't publish it correctly (the build results in the folders: bin, Properties, Views, wwwroot, and the configuration files).

I dont know what im doing wrong here, i have searched the web for a couple of days and still wasnt able to figure out what i did wrong. Please advice.

**Note**: to be able to build in the first place, i had to add to my .NET Core's project .csproj file the following lines so it wont fail while building:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="true" />
```

**The command line to execute the build**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" DailyBuild.proj /t:DailyBuild /p:VersionNumber=15
```

**DailyBuild.proj**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourcesPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\</SourcesPath>
    <CSCleanProperties>BuildType=Clean;Configuration=Release;IsFormalBuild=true</CSCleanProperties>
    <CSBuildProperties>BuildType=ReBuild;Configuration=Release;PauseBuildOnError=false;PublishWebSites=true;VersionName=Prod-$(VersionNumber)</CSBuildProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="DailyBuildWithClean">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make2.proj" Targets="Clean" Properties="$(CSCleanProperties)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make2.proj" Properties="$(CSCleanProperties)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make2.proj" Targets="FormalBuild" Properties="$(CSBuildProperties)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DailyBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make2.proj" Targets="SW;PreparePackFolder" Properties="$(CSBuildProperties)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

**Make2.proj**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="SW" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="CreateProperties;Clean">
  <ItemGroup>
    <SourcesPathItem Include='$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\' />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.v1.4.0.88</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
    <CSConfiguration>$(Configuration)</CSConfiguration>
    <BuildType Condition=" '$(BuildType)' == '' ">Build</BuildType>
    <PauseBuildOnError>true</PauseBuildOnError>
    <PublishWebSites>false</PublishWebSites>
    <IsFormalBuild>false</IsFormalBuild>
    <VersionName>Prod</VersionName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CreateProperties" >
    <CreateProperty Value="%(SourcesPathItem.Fullpath)Src\">
      <Output PropertyName="SourcesPath" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="%(SourcesPathItem.Fullpath)Artifacts\">
      <Output PropertyName="MainArtifactsFolder" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="%(SourcesPathItem.Fullpath)Packages\">
      <Output PropertyName="PackageFolder" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="%(SourcesPathItem.Fullpath)Artifacts\DeployedArtifacts\">
      <Output PropertyName="DeployedPackageFolder" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="%(SourcesPathItem.Fullpath)Src\Util\InspectorWebService\InspectorWebService\Publish\">
      <Output PropertyName="InspectorWebServicePublishPath" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </CreateProperty>

  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CSPlatformIndependentProjectProperties>Configuration=$(CSConfiguration);Platform=AnyCPU</CSPlatformIndependentProjectProperties>
    <CSPlatformSpecificProjectProperties>Configuration=$(CSConfiguration);Platform=$(Platform)</CSPlatformSpecificProjectProperties>
    <VCConfiguration>Configuration=$(CSConfiguration);Platform=Win32</VCConfiguration>
  </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="InspectorWebService">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(InspectorWebServicePublishPath)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SourcesPath)Util\InspectorWebService\InspectorWebService\InspectorWebService.csproj" Targets="$(BuildType)" Properties="$(CSPlatformIndependentProjectProperties)"/>
    <MSBuild Condition=" '$(BuildType)' != 'Clean' And '$(PublishWebSites)' == 'true' " Projects="$(SourcesPath)Util\InspectorWebService\InspectorWebService\InspectorWebService.csproj"
             Targets="ResolveReferences;_WPPCopyWebApplication" Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=$(InspectorWebServicePublishPath);BuildingProject=true" />
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllProcessesTargets>
      InspectorWebService;
    </AllProcessesTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="SW">
    <CallTarget Targets="$(AllProcessesTargets)" RunEachTargetSeparately="false"/>
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="PauseBuild"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="FormalBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="SW;PreparePackFolder;Pack"/>
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="ErrorHandler"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PreparePackFolder">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(MainArtifactsFolder)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(MainArtifactsFolder)" />  

    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="PreparePackFolderInternal" Properties="ArtifactFormat=Old;MixedArtifiactFolder=$(MainArtifactsFolder)MixedArtifacts\"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="PreparePackFolderInternal" Properties="ArtifactFormat=New;MixedArtifiactFolder=$(MainArtifactsFolder)DeployedArtifacts\"/>
   </Target>
  <Target Name="PreparePackFolderInternal">
    <CallTarget Targets="PrepareInspectorWebServiceToPack;PrepareOtherFolders"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyDefaultFiles">
    <Exec Condition=" '$(ArtifactFormat)' == 'Old'" Command="xcopy &quot;$(CompleteBinFolder)*.*&quot; &quot;$(MixedArtifiactFolder)$(ComponenetName)\Binaries&quot; /I /Y /D /E /F"/>
    <Exec Condition=" '$(ArtifactFormat)' == 'New'" Command="xcopy &quot;$(CompleteBinFolder)*.*&quot; &quot;$(MixedArtifiactFolder)$(ComponenetName)&quot; /I /Y /D /E /F"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <GeneralConfigFiles Include="$(MixedArtifiactFolder)$(ComponenetName)\Binaries\*.config"/>
      <PDBFiles Include="$(MixedArtifiactFolder)$(ComponenetName)\**\*.pdb"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Move Condition=" '$(ArtifactFormat)' == 'Old'" SourceFiles="@(GeneralConfigFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(MixedArtifiactFolder)$(ComponenetName)\Configurations"/>
    <Move Condition=" '$(ArtifactFormat)' == 'New'" SourceFiles="@(PDBFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(MainArtifactsFolder)PDBs\$(ComponenetName)"/>
    <Delete Condition=" '$(ArtifactFormat)' == 'Old'" Files="@(PDBFiles)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PrepareInspectorWebServiceToPack" Condition=" '$(BuildType)' != 'Clean' ">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="CopyDefaultFiles" Properties="CompleteBinFolder=$(InspectorWebServicePublishPath);ComponenetName=InspectorWebService"/>
  </Target>


  <Target Name="PrepareOtherFolders">
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SourcesPath)..\Certificates\*.*&quot; &quot;$(MixedArtifiactFolder)Certificates&quot; /I /Y /D /E /F"/>
    <Exec Command="xcopy &quot;$(SourcesPath)\Resources\CCI\*.*&quot; &quot;$(DeployedPackageFolder)CCI\Configuration\&quot; /I /Y /D /E /F"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Pack" Condition=" '$(BuildType)' != 'Clean' ">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PackageFolder)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PackageFolder)" />


    <ItemGroup>
      <InspectorWebServiceFilesForZip Include="$(DeployedPackageFolder)InspectorWebService\**\*.*" Exclude="$(DeployedPackageFolder)InspectorWebService\**\*.pdb" />
    </ItemGroup> 
    <Zip ZipFileName="$(PackageFolder)$(VersionName)-InspectorWebService.zip" WorkingDirectory="$(DeployedPackageFolder)InspectorWebService" Files="@(InspectorWebServiceFilesForZip)" ZipLevel="9" ParallelCompression="false" />



    <ItemGroup>
      <AllZipFiles Include="$(DeployedPackageFolder)\**\*.*" Exclude="$(DeployedPackageFolder)\**\*.pdb" />
    </ItemGroup> 
    <Zip ZipFileName="$(PackageFolder)$(VersionName)-!All.zip" WorkingDirectory="$(DeployedPackageFolder)" Files="@(AllZipFiles)" ZipLevel="9" ParallelCompression="false" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <AllPDBFiles Include="$(MainArtifactsFolder)PDBs\**\*.pdb"/>
    </ItemGroup> 
    <Zip ZipFileName="$(PackageFolder)$(VersionName)-!PDBForAll.zip" WorkingDirectory="$(MainArtifactsFolder)PDBs" Files="@(AllPDBFiles)" ZipLevel="9" ParallelCompression="false" />

  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean" Condition=" '$(BuildType)' == 'Clean' ">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(InspectorWebServicePublishPath)"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PackageFolder)"/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(MixedArtifiactFolder)"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PauseBuild" Condition=" '$(PauseBuildOnError)' == 'true' ">
    <Prompt Text="Press any key to continue ..." />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ErrorHandler">

  </Target>
</Project>
```